# Getting a null return from BufferedReader

Tags: java, bufferedreader

So I'm trying to upload an image to Imgur using their v3 API (http://api.imgur.com/) and when I get the response it returns me with

```
null : null
```

Here is my full code.

```
import java.util.List;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.util.ArrayList;

import javax.imageio.ImageIO;

import org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Base64;
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.entity.UrlEncodedFormEntity;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.apache.http.message.BasicNameValuePair;
//import org.omg.DynamicAny.NameValuePair;
import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;

public class Upload {

    public static void main (String[] args) {

        System.out.println(Imgur("C:\\Users\\wiesa\\Desktop\\image.jpg",     "2313fab45c25337"));
    }

public static String Imgur (String imageDir, String clientID) {
    //create needed strings
    String address = "https://api.imgur.com/3/image";

    //Create HTTPClient and post
    HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpPost post = new HttpPost(address);

    //create base64 image
    BufferedImage image = null;
    File file = new File(imageDir);

    try {
        //read image
        image = ImageIO.read(file);
        ByteArrayOutputStream byteArray = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        ImageIO.write(image, "png", byteArray);
        byte[] byteImage = byteArray.toByteArray();
        String dataImage = new Base64().encodeAsString(byteImage);

        //add header
        post.addHeader("Authorization", "Client-ID" + clientID);
        //add image
        List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(1);
        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("image", dataImage));
        post.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));

        //execute
        HttpResponse response = client.execute(post);

        //read response
        BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(new     InputStreamReader(response.getEntity().getContent()));
        String all = null;

        //loop through response
        while (rd.readLine() != null) {
            all = all + " : " + rd.readLine(); 
        }

        return all;

    }
    catch (Exception e){
        return "error: " + e.toString();
    }
}
}
```

Depending what I initilize the string "all" to if I make it a

```
null
```

Then the return is

> null : null

BUt if I initialize it to

```
""
```

Then the return is

> : null

I Changed the line to

```
String all = null;

    //loop through response
    String line = null;
    while ((line = rd.readLine()) != null) {
        all = all + " : " + line;
    }

    return all;
```

and the I get the return

> null : {"data":{"error":"Malformed auth header","request":"/3/image","parameters":"image = iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAB4AAAASwCAIAAACVUsChAACAAElEQVR42uzdCXebyrI2YEuyY8fzPCbZOyfZd597v///...","method":"POST"},"success":false,"status":403}

Answer (score 4, accepted):

At each iteration, you're reading two lines instead of one. Change

```
while (rd.readLine() != null) { // first line read
    all = all + " : " + rd.readLine(); // second line read
}
```

to

```
String line;
while ((line = rd.readLine()) != null) {
    all = all + " : " + line;
}
```

Comment: Updated the original post with what happens after changing that while statement.

Comment: So, that seems to have solved the problem: you got a response. What's your question?

Comment: Well it looks like I have a 403 error which means

> Forbidden. You don't have access to this action. If you're getting this error, check that you haven't run out of API credits or make sure you're sending the OAuth headers correctly and have valid tokens/secrets.

I know I have enough tokens and my secret is correct so that means I'm sending a wrong header but I don't know how to solve this.

Comment: That's a completely different question than the original one. Consider asking another question.

Comment: It isn't necessary to initialize the string.